# Adding citations with R code in Rmarkdown document

Tags: r, r-markdown, officer, officedown

To add a citation in Rmarkdown we can just type `[@Author]` in the document. I wonder if it's possible to do this with R code.

The pseudo code for my expected solution:

```
# just markdown
This is my markdown content and here is a great book about it: `r insert_citation()`.
```

where `insert_citation` is a function like this:

```
insert_citation <- function() "[@Author]"
```

This should produce the output like this (assuming I already prepared the bibliography for the document):

```
This is my markdown content and here is a great book about it: (A. Uthor 2021).
```

The point is that I need to add a citation conditionally based on data. If a condition is satisfied there should be the citation in the document, otherwise skip the citation.
My document is a docx. Any hints related to officedown or officer packages are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to use `invisible()` and a wrapper around `cite`.

````
---
title: "cite"
output: word_document
bibliography: refs.bib
---
```{r refs, include=FALSE}
db <- bibentry(
   bibtype = "Manual",
   title = "R: A Language and Environment for Statistical Computing",
   author = person("R Core Team"),
   organization = "R Foundation for Statistical Computing",
   address = "Vienna, Austria",
   year = 2013,
   url = "https://www.R-project.org/",
   key = "R")

f <- function(cond, ref) if(cond) cite(ref, db) else invisible()
```

This is some text `r f(TRUE, "R")` but don't cite this `r f(FALSE, "R")`

`r if(TRUE) "[@R]"` but not `r if(FALSE) "[@R]"`
````

[image]

If you have a bib file, simply returning a string with the regular citation structure is sufficient, as shown in the last line.

There are likely better alternatives such as [parameterized reports](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/parameterized-reports.html) if you have to do this for multiple reports or multiple references.

Comment: this is great, I didn't know cite function. No, I need to do this for only one reference. Do You know how to get rid of the db object? I generate the bibliography from a .bib file, not create it manually

Comment: @JakubMałecki Sure, `rmarkdown` takes string R output as if it were regular typed text, edited the answer

Comment: I found rbibutils package to be helpful and can be used with cite function. This is the case when one loads the bibliography from a bib file